# insert not working on php remote site

Tags: php, mysql

So I have this php file which works absolutely fine offline. When I take it on the remote server, there's one particular table where the 'INSERT' command does not work. The connection and user privileges seem to be all correct because it works on other tables.

Here's the code:

```
  $addLvl="INSERT into levels (buyer_id, l1_pr, l2_pr, l3_pr, l4_pr, l5_pr, l6_pr, l7_pr) values ('$num_code','$Pcode','$l2_pr','$l3_pr','$l4_pr','$l5_pr','$l6_pr','$l7_pr')";
 $runLvl=mysqli_query($con,$addLvl);
```

the same file worked absolutely fine on a second remote location.

Comment: you are getting any errors??

Comment: no, does not show any error.

Comment: while doing submission inspect  and check in console it will show some errors surely.. or else debug line by line you will found out the error definitely.

Comment: Interestingly I tried out on another client's server, and it works fine.

Comment: oh..!!! thats fine but check from your end why it is coming like that.

Comment: put a conditional check for connection status , like if (!$conn) then die() with the error so you know if your connection is set correctly

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.error.php